# peer.js is not working http but not on https?

Tags: express, https, webrtc, peer

when i used this http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/peerjs/0.3.14/peer.js 
its was giving following error

> was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script
>   'http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/peerjs/0.3.14/peer.js'. This
>   request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

after adding 
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/peerjs/0.3.14/peer.js
its started giving

> was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest
>   endpoint '0.peerjs.com:9000/c03lztxhq78vkj4i/…;. This request has been
>   blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Comment: Is the webpage in which you are trying to access peer.js is being loaded over https?

Comment: yes my page is loaded over https  which is accessing peer.js

Comment: If your page is loaded over https, then all the content you try to load within it has to be over https only. If you try to use http the browser blocks it for security reasons. So I think in your case, peer.js is trying to load something over http within it. If you can then try loading your page over http once just to verify if what I said is true.

Comment: I tried loading my page over http  then i got   " getUserMedia() no longer works on insecure origins. To use this feature, you should consider switching your application to a secure origin, such as HTTPS. See https://goo.gl/rStTGz for more details." Warning and the video is not required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check its compatability support of peerjs http://peerjs.com/status/old

Comment: Yeah i was not checking for browsers compatibility

Comment: Also check its last changes are December 22nd, 2013

Answer (score 3):

This is due to mixed-content blocking - try loading the secure version e.g.

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/peerjs/0.3.14/peer.js
```

Comment: i've added https its started giving  "was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://0.peerjs.com:9000/c03lztxhq78vkj4i/id?ts=14517230738410.733534500701353'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS."

Comment: It's not because of the location of the `peer.js` file but inside this script it tries to access insecure domain.

Answer (score 0):

**Might be late but anyways this might help some ...**

In case of **Peer Js** :

If you’re planning to deploy to a remote server, it has to be via HTTPS. This is because browsers only allows to access device if connection is secure.

[This article](https://www.sitepoint.com/webrtc-video-chat-application-peerjs/) might help ( Read under the title: **Deploying to remote server** ).

If curious, also consider having a look at [web fundamentals](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/prevent-mixed-content/what-is-mixed-content). ( Read under the title : **An XMLHttpRequest example** ).

*Extra stuff :* You can also read [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/prevent-mixed-content/fixing-mixed-content) to prevent mixed content.