# Using PeerJs For Live streaming

Tags: javascript, ssl, https, webrtc, peerjs

There is already a question [peer.js is not working http but not on https?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34526740/peer-js-is-not-working-http-but-not-on-https) but its marked answered for checking browser compatibility.

It has also a comment [peer.js is not working http but not on https?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34526740/peer-js-is-not-working-http-but-not-on-https#comment-63784764) that tells real problem

I am using chrome 64.0.3282.140 and tried different versions and browsers, so peerjs compatibility test results already fine but still

For using navigator.getUserMedia one need to run the web app at secure domain (https)

But then this app does not connect peerjs server with following error

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://localhost:4200' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://0.peerjs.com:9000/peerjs/id?ts=xyz'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS

Moreover using peer.js from secure cdn link makes no difference as it still calls same url as above http://0.peerjs.com:9000/peerjs/id?ts=xyz and unfortunately the url does not work when **i tried to change it to https**

**Is there any secure resource available from peerjs So that I can use getUserMedia?**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I see this in their docs at https://peerjs.com/docs/#start

> secure BOOLEAN BETA (0.3.0) 
>   true if you're using SSL. Note that our
>   cloud-hosted server and assets may not support SSL.

Sounds like you need to host your own server...